# Iterate through ListView navigation items

Tags: android, navigation-drawer

I'm using the Activity with Navigation Drawer project template within Android Studio, which generates the navigation menu like this:

```
mDrawerListView.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(
                getActionBar().getThemedContext(),
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
                android.R.id.text1,
                new String[]{
                        getString(R.string.title_section1),
                        getString(R.string.title_section2),
                        getString(R.string.title_section3),
                }));
```

I'm looking for an easy way to be able to iterate through those items and update the subtext on some of them with new information. So I attempted to change `android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1` to `android.R.layout.simple_list_item_2` within the `setAdapter()` call, and loop through them like this:

```
View v;
TextView tv;
for(int i = 0; i < mDrawerListView.getCount(); i++){
    v = mDrawerListView.getAdapter().getView(i,null,null);
    tv = (TextView) v.findViewById(android.R.id.text2);
    tv.setText("Sub Item");
}
```

Which doesn't work, but it doesn't throw any errors. I've also tried just using `getChildAt()` rather than going through `getAdapter()`, which has resulted in a null reference error.

What's the best way to approach this particular issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same issue, but the solution is pretty simple. You just need to override the getView method of the adapter:

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
```

You can keep the normal behaviour of this method and add whatever you want to do, so for example in your case you'd want to add something like this:

```
    @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View view= super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
        TextView tv= (TextView) view.findViewById(android.R.id.text2);
        tv.setText("sub text");
        }
```

This should work.

Comment: I ended up doing something like this, and it seems to be the closest to what I need!